# I want the models in partial view and index view to be different

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

They want me to make a page dynamic. There are slider, galery, form and subscribe sections in the page. I need to associate these partitions with the database. I divided these parts into partials. I inserted the slider part in the index view because it is only on the main page.

```
@model IEnumerable<SekizgenApplication.Models.Slider>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="justics-holder">

    <div id="carousel-example-generic102" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->

        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (@item.Active == true)
                {
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="justices-img">
                            <img src="~/Slider/@item.sliderDosyaYolu" width="700" height="600" alt="image" class="img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="justices-img">
                        <img src="~/Slider/@item.sliderDosyaYolu" width="700" height="600" alt="image" class="img">
                    </div>
                </div>
            }


        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control prev-2" href="#carousel-example-generic102" role="button" data-slide="prev">

            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

            <span class="sr-only">Geri</span>

        </a>

        <a class="right carousel-control next-2" href="#carousel-example-generic102" role="button" data-slide="next">

            <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

            <span class="sr-only">İleri</span>

        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

I created partial for gallery part. By the way, I created a table in the database for each section. Galery section codes are as follows:

```
@model IEnumerable<SekizgenApplication.Models.Galery>

<div class="page-section black">
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="gallery-heading">
                    <h1>EĞİTİM KURUMUZDAN KARELER</h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">


                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="gallery-img">
                                            <img src="~/Galery/@item.picDosyaYolu" width="360" height="350" alt="image">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }


                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-box">
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Geri</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">İleri</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem came out when adding this partial galery part to the layout.

```
@Html.Partial("_GaleryPartial")
```

when I added this, I got an error because the index is different from the one model and the partial model is different. How we can solve this problem?

Comment: What does your main view and layout look like?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a third view model for your main page that contains your two existing models as properties (*or however many view models/partials you want on that screen*)

The new view model could look something like this:

```
public class MainVm 
{
    public IEnumerable<SekizgenApplication.Models.Slider> Sliders { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SekizgenApplication.Models.Galery> Galeries { get; set; }
}
```

You could then pass these properties to your partials from the cshtml page like so:

```
@model SekizgenApplication.Models.MainVm

@Html.Partial("_GaleryPartial", Model.Galeries)
@Html.Partial("_SliderPartial", Model.Sliders)
```

This should solve the error you are getting.